# is java 9 and above still platform independent or not after this module system has been introduced?

Tags: java, java-9, java-10, java-11

I am not able to understand that after module system is introduced in our java language. Is java9 and above still platform independent or not ? I am asking this question because I have read that now every application will have its own jre inside it. So, how will this single jre run on all OS, like windows, Linux, or Mac OS.

Comment: Tried JDK on different platforms? that might help you undeerstand..

Comment: Do we really need jdk/ jre on client machines to run our java application when webstart and java plugins are getting removed in java 11?

Comment: I meant correlating and not that it would be necessary to have them. Creating custom JRE using `jlink` is a resource you can browse to read further about the change and progress made by people on that aspect.

Comment: You've always needed platform-specific JREs/JVMs to run Java code. When embedding the JRE you need to package the correct one for the target platform.

Comment: Well this was my only concern that when we are packaging and embedding a particular JRE for some particular platform.Then our java program doesn"t remain platform independent. Whereas earlier one jar file was running on any platform with the help of JRE"s. So now we need to create platform specific java applications. Am I correct ?

Comment: You *can* bundle your application with a jre. You don’t have to. Look at how Eclipse and Netbeans offer bundled versions for certain common platforms while still offering a generic Java version with the highest portability (for more than a decade). It’s a matter of convenience. Of course, it’s in the hands of the application vendors to still offer a pure Java version, just like it always was in their hands, to write a truly platform independent software, i.e. not to rely on system specific artifacts or behavior in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are conflating **two different changes** recently made to the Java platform:

- Retiring of Java Web Start & Applet technologies
- Modularization

## Retiring desktop-technologies

Recently Oracle announced the phasing out of the [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) technologies, in addition to the [already-deprecated Applet](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/289) technology. See item [*JDK-8184998*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html#JDK-8184998) in Java 9 Release Notes:

> **Java Deployment Technologies are deprecated and will be removed in a future release**
>
> Java Applet and WebStart functionality, including the Applet API, The Java plug-in, the Java Applet Viewer, JNLP and Java Web Start including the javaws tool are all deprecated in JDK 9 and will be removed in a future release.

End-users will no longer be encouraged to install a JDK or JRE on their computer.

For more details, see the eight-page 2018-03 white paper from Oracle, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf).

So then, how are developers of [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) or [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) apps to deliver their software to the end-user?

Oracle suggests packaging up your app along with a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) & [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Java_Runtime_Environment) for delivery as a single launch-ready applications on that appears on the client to be just another app alongside the native apps. Such “double-clickable” app-packaging has been commonly done on the Mac since the beginning of Java. But what was once an obscure art on other host environments ([Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution), [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), etc.) will now be the norm, as it is on macOS.

In yesteryear, bundling a Java runtime with your app required jumping over some [licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license) hurdles. The legalities have eased with arrival of the open-source [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project, and possibly with other implementations<sup>†</sup>.

You will need to prepare different releases of your app for each hosting environment. While your Java code runs independently of the host OS, the JVM is built of native code to interact with one specific kind of host. So you will need to build a Linux release with a Linux JVM, a macOS release with a macOS JVM, and so on. While that may seem like a downer, the upside is that you no longer need to worry about users having the wrong JVM version installed, or no JVM at all. Now the JVM’s presence and version are under your control. Your end-users and customers will no longer need to be aware that your app is Java-based.

## Modularization

That need for app-packaging has nothing to do with the [modularization of Java](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=376). As I said, it has been done for decades on the Mac.

What modularization brings to the party is that the JVM/JRE you bundle into your delivered app can be customized to contain only the Java Modules actually utilized by your particular app. This results in a smaller size, so your finished app is smaller, downloads are faster, less storage is used, and your app may load faster.

The open-source [*jlink*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282) “Java Linker” tool helps with the packaging work, so you can assemble and optimize a set of modules and their dependencies (only the ones actually called by your app) into a custom run-time image. This modular run-time image format is defined in [JEP 220](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220).

---

<sup>†</sup> On a related note, you may want to read the white paper [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04) to understand how and where to obtain a Java implementation for your app, and what support may or may not be offered in either free-of-cost or paid releases.

---

By the way, you may find helpful [this Answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/55079/1255) on a [related Question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/55078/1255), with a flowchart of choosing various sources of a Java implementation.

Answer (score 6):

> Is java9 and above still platform independent or not ?

Yes. It's as platform independent as it ever was. The module system has nothing to do with platform independence.

> now every application will have its own jre inside it.

It doesn't have to, but it's more and more recommended as time goes on since **fewer people have Java installed separately on their systems.** This *used* to be a given, but that number has been declining for the last decade or so, and now (outside of Java developers) pretty much no-one has a standalone JRE installed.

> how will this single jre run on all OS

It won't. You will bundle a separate JRE for each platform you want to distribute for. But JRE's for all platforms are still freely available, and the same Java code will still run on a JRE for any platform.

Answer (score 5):

The *module system* doesn't influence the OS independency of java in general. Java applications that make use of the module system *need to be run in a JRE*. This can be either an OS specific pre-installed JRE as usual or a tailored runtime image (application embedded JRE) created with [JLink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9).

The module systems main purpose is to provide you a managed way to split your application into different logical modules. E.g. into different *.jar* files that can be loaded at runtime - no matter on which operating system.

**In summary, you have the following options:**

- Make sure that your client has the right JRE pre-installed. This could be dangerous, because (normally) you are not in control of his updating behavior.
- Ship your application together with an official JRE.
- Tailor your own, *application and OS specific* runtime image using *JLink*. Ship it bundled with your application.

  > But, suppose I do not know what OS my client would be running so how
  >   the server will decide what image he should give to him. i.e., a Mac
  >   Image, a Linux Image or a Windows exe.

  You have to know the target OS and deliver the right runtime image.

Comment: Well my question was not about module system instead it was about Platform Independence. I know how module system works. But, suppose I do not know what OS my client would be running so how the server will decide what image he should give to him. i.e., a Mac Image, a Linux Image or a Windows exe. Also to create these images now developer would need to compile the same program on 3 different machine, so that we are able to ship it.

Answer (score 4):

While Java 9 makes it easier to ship a JRE which is more compact and specific to the needs of an individual application, you are not required to do so.  If you were already planning to ship a JRE with your application it can be smaller with Java 9 than earlier versions.

It doesn't mean you have to ship a JRE, an application which wasn't shipped with a JRE is unlikely to start shipping with one now, and in fact Java 11 only ships as a JDK.

From this [link on Java 9 features](https://dzone.com/articles/the-next-generation-of-java-application-deployment);

> JLink allows you to create custom runtime images that only consist of your application modules and those JRE modules that your application requires. The result is likely a smaller runtime image, which uses fewer resources than a default JRE.

Comment: see the link https://dzone.com/articles/the-next-generation-of-java-application-deployment